# Gson Instance Creator created instance, but fields are null

Tags: java, json, rest, gson

I have this JSON string..

```
{"id":0,"entryDate":1497716236038,"guestName":"a","bookingRooms":[{"id":0,"bookingId":0,"roomId":2,"startDate":0,"endDate":0}]}
```

And this is the parsed result from Gson..

```
Booking [id=0, entryDate=Sat Jun 17 21:47:16 IST 2017, 
 guestName=a, bookingRooms=[
  BookingRoom [id=null, bookingId=null, roomId=null, startDate=null, endDate=null]
 ]
]
```

As you can see, all the fields of the `BookingRoom` instance turned out to be `null`. But, the input has at least zeroes for the fields.

In my type structure, the `List<IBookingRooms>` in `Booking` class is an interface. I registered an `InstanceCreator` with Gson so that I can do a new instance of `BookingRoom` class.

My understanding is that once I give Gson the blank instance from the InstanceCreator hook, it should be able to set the fields from the Json string. However, that doesn't happen.

Am I missing something? Could you suggest how to fix this?

Second problem is that, even with an empty array for bookingRooms in the input JSON string, still the parsed list has the same one item in the list with all fields null!

JSON string..

```
{"id":0,"entryDate":1497716236038,"guestName":"a","bookingRooms":[]}
```

And still one empty instance is there in the `List`!

```
Booking [id=0, entryDate=Sat Jun 17 21:47:16 IST 2017, 
 guestName=a, bookingRooms=[
  BookingRoom [id=null, bookingId=null, roomId=null, startDate=null, endDate=null]
 ]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `InstanceCreator` class seems to be a solution only to the "instance creation" problem, i.e., a constructor problem. This is applicable when the class is a concrete class, but that concrete class doesn't have a no-args constructor.

In the case of an interface, there is another problem as well. Gson relies on member variables to figure out the list of fields to serialize and deserialize. In the case of an interface, Gson concludes that there are 0 fields to deserialize.

So, once the instance creator creates a concrete instance, still Gson doesn't copy any of the fields. This is because it had built the field list by reflection on the interface.

The solution was to use a `JsonDeserializer`.